# Qual a diferença entre função e método?

Tags: javascript

Em várias referências é mencionado comandos da sintaxe do *JavaScript* como `addEventListener()`, `pop()`, `querySelector()` e etc como métodos:

[treinaweb](https://www.treinaweb.com.br/blog/javascript-metodos-de-arrays-que-voce-precisa-conhecer/)

[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_string_methods.asp)

Mas o próprio *MDN Web Docs* define esses comandos como funções e não métodos:

[MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Aprender/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basico#O_que_aconteceu)

Então eu parei por aqui não sei qual são as diferenças entre os dois no caso para mim até agora um método é uma função dentro de um objeto:

```js
let a = {
  b: function() {
    return "Olá";
  }
}
```

Então se eu quisesse, por exemplo, verificar se em um elemento possui uma determinada classe eu teria que escrever algo como `classList.container('class1')` ou seja `classList` é um objeto e eu estou acessando o seu método que é `container()`.

Já uma função para mim é algo que não tem a necessidade de declarar algo anteriormente como, por exeplo:

```js
function res(a, b) {
    return a * b;
}
```

Essa é a minha perspectiva, mas em questão do certo ou errado qual é a diferença entre os dois termos?

Comment: Essa também aborda o tema: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/212265/fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-e-m%C3%A9todo-s%C3%A3o-a-mesma-coisa

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Quais são as definições de método, função e procedimento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11848/quais-s%c3%a3o-as-defini%c3%a7%c3%b5es-de-m%c3%a9todo-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-e-procedimento)

Comment: Vlw! pelas referências apesar de não ter uma fonte concreta da especificação além da Wikipedia deduzindo o real significado de cada um dos termos eu vou continuar  com o pensamento de cima e que nem o das respostas dos links citados.

Answer (score -2):

Método é uma função associada à estrutura de dados de um objeto. Quando você chama a.b(), presume-se que b() vai ler e/ou escrever dados no objeto "a". Isso pode acontecer de forma indireta, se a.b() chamar outros métodos do objeto.

Posso escrever um método que na realidade não interage de forma nenhuma com o objeto? Pode, mas não deve; ele deveria ser um método estático (associado a uma classe, não a um objeto) ou mesmo uma função.