# Diferença entre método e função?

Tags: java, kotlin

Porque em Java se chama método e no Kotlin se chama função, é apenas uma nomenclatura diferente, ou existe alguma diferença significante?

```
Java:

public class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int result = multiplicaDois(2);      
        System.out.print(result);
    }

    public static int multiplicaDois(int x) {
        return 2 * x; 
    }
}


Kotlin:

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val result = multiplicaDois(2);
    println(result);    
}

fun multiplicaDois(x: Int): Int {
    return 2 * x;
}
```

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11848/57801

Comment: Basicamente não se tem nenhuma diferença, no passado esta diferença na teoria existia. O que se tem por padrão é que as funções que existem dentro de uma classe tem o nome de método, por ser métodos que são executados pela classe.
É mais como definição de linguagens que usam orientação objeto.